# Как добавить элементы из одного блока в другой на js?

Tags: javascript

Изначально имеются два списка из div'ов:

```
<div id="one">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Как переместить элементы из второго списка в первый?
Результат должен быть такой:

```
<div id="one">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
</div>
```

Что-то все пытался, да так и не вышло сделать.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: нужно [взять детей](https://api.jquery.com/children/) и [добавить их](https://api.jquery.com/append/) в нужный элемент

Comment: @Grundy, нужно на на чистом js. И обратите внимание, в каком порядке их туда нужно добавить.

Comment: то же самое, только добавляется цикл по [детям](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) и [добавка чуть меняется](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one'),
  two = document.getElementById('two'),
  oneChilds = one.children,
  twoChilds = two.children,
  twoChildsLength = twoChilds.length;

for(let i = 0; i < twoChildsLength ; i++) {
  one.insertBefore(twoChilds[0], oneChilds[i * 2 + 1]);
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Так как надо перенести все элементы из `#two`, то перебираем по их кол-ву:

```
for(let i = 0; i < twoChildsLength ; i++) { ... }
```

Для вставки в `#one` используем метод

`parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)`

- `parentElement` - Родитель для нового элемента.
- `newElement` - Элемент для вставки.
- `referenceElement` - Элемент, перед которым будет вставлен newElement.

При чем, если `referenceElement` будет равен `null/undefined`, то `newElement` будет вставлен в конец списка дочерних элементов `parentElement` - что собственно нам и нужно.

Учитывая то, что после каждой итерации коллекции элементов (`oneChilds`, `twoChilds`) будут меняться, то переносить нам всегда нужно только первый (`twoChilds[0]`), а вот вставлять нужно перед каждым `n * 2 + 1`, так как после каждой итерации в коллекцию `oneChilds` будут добавляться новые элементы:

```
el_1[id] 
el_2[0]  // вставлен перед элементом с id = 1
el_1[id] // 0 * 2 + 1 = 1
...      // сюда вставится следующий элемент
el_1[id] // 1 * 2 + 1 = 3
// до вставки этот элемент имеет id = 3, после вставки будет id = 4
```

Когда `oneChilds[id]` (в данном случае на 3+ итерациях) не будет найден, все оставшиеся элементы из `twoChilds` будут просто вставляться в конец списка дочерних элементов `one`

Comment: Практически отлично. Последний элемент остается во втором списке.

Comment: @Jimmy, да, тоже заметил, сейчас попробую понять в чем проблема

Comment: @Jimmy, поправил

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Добавь пояснения в ответ

Comment: @Grundy, осознал как я слаб в пояснениях ... =/

Answer (score 0):

В две строчки: перенос элементов из блока a в блок b

```
var count = a.childNodes.length;
for(var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    b.appendChild(a.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Или даже так

```
while (a.childNodes.length != 0) b.appendChild(a.childNodes[0]);
```